# Would like to downscale deployment replicas to 1

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

Currently, the deployment replicas are set as 2. I'm trying to scale down deployments to 1 using the below command

```
kubectl scale deploy -n myspace  --replicas=1 --all
```

it terminates but spins back to 2. How can I scale down?

Comment: is there any `argoCD` or any other CI/CD that auto syncs back the deployment with the git source?

Comment: There could also the HPA and due to resource usage might be scaling it up.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response. Issue resolved. HPA was defined that was the reason.